# download two files in the same file

Tags: android

How could I do so that when downloading the file, it is not replaced, but rather another file is created but it is the same. that in the cell phone folder there are two files, if I download the same file and give it another time to download, there are two files.
I was using this flag PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT.

```
private String createPdf(String name, String pdfBase64) {
    byte[] pdfBytesData = Base64.decode(pdfBase64, Base64.DEFAULT);
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), name);
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
    try {
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    try {
        fileOutputStream.write(pdfBytesData);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        try {
            fileOutputStream.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return file.getPath();
}
```

Comment: If you want to download the same file twice, you'd need to give it a different name when you save it to the filesystem.  Its impossible to have two files with the same name in the same directory-  a path is unique.

Comment: @Override
    public void onSuccessFetchLabReport(LabReportResponse response) {
        String pdfFilePath = createPdf(
                "Receta_" + idCita+".pdf",//creo que el cambio seria aqui!!
                response.getData().getReportBase64());
        if (pdfFilePath != null) showNotificationComplete(pdfFilePath);
        else showNotificationFail();
        jobFinished(params, false);
    }

Comment: here I am giving the name

Comment: the name-  the first parameter to createPdf-  must be different for every call or it will overwrite the older file with that name.  From your code I have no idea if its doing that, because I have no idea what idCita is and when it changes.

Comment: I would like to consult you in a more private way,since I understand you a little

Comment: you mean you want to append first file with second file?